# Why is my bitshift operand casting on an unsupported 'str' type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a function that takes a user input between 0 and 31.5, increments of 0.5, and creates a binary word from the input based on a set of mod values. But when I feed the function with valid user inputs, I get the following TypeError:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'bytes' and 'str'
```

Here is the function I have built:

```
def binary_word(user_input):
   mod_range = [16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5]
   word = b'00000000'
   mask = b'00000001'

   for i in range(len(mod_range)):
      # if the mod num is greater than user input, skip
      if mod_range[i] > user_input:
         continue

      # otherwise, bitshift the mask to build the binary word through the iterations
      elif mod_range[i] == user_input or remainder > 0:
         mask << len(mod_range) - i 
         word = word | mask    # <------------------------ this is where the TypeError occures***
         user_input -= user_input % mod_range[i]
         mask = b'00000001'

   print(f"output word: {word}")
```

My mod values are [16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5].

So if the user input is 12, I would like the function to return a binary word as such:

```
b'00011000'

corresponding to this order of mod nums [0,0,16,8,4,2,1,0.5]
```

| Mod List | Binary Word |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 16 | 0 |

Comment: What is `mask << len(mod_range) - i` supposed to do? That expression returns a new value, __nothing changes in place here__.

Comment: `word` is a byte string, not an integer value, so yes, you get a type error there. You can't bit-shift strings.

Comment: You seem to be expecting that literals like `b'00000001'` produce a binary number - no, that's just a string that happens to contain only two distinct characters. `0b00000001` is how you write a binary number literal.

Comment: If you wanted to use bit masking, you'll have to use integer values. The bytestring `b'00000001'` is not a sequence of bits, it's a sequence of bytes, here representing the ascii characters `'0'` and `'1'`, and is not an integer value. You can use the `0b....` prefix to specify an integer value using binary notation, don't confuse that with `b'...'` byte string literals.

Comment: Last but not least: **always** include the traceback of exceptions. The error in this code happens on the line _above_ the one with the comment that says `this is where the TypeError occures`. The full traceback not only would show us this much more accurately, but also how Python got there.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters, you helped me solve a few mistakes. I've amended the function, it's now returning expected conversions.